# WesternDigital My Passport Ultra creates strange folders

Tags: hard-drive

I have bought WD MY PASSPORT ULTRA one year ago and didn't have any problems till now. Strangely named folders create automatic like:

- 21f6f6c95cd7485f8f1b
- fde4dbe0ee62bce74f96a9a6dde8

What to do ? I have important information for me on this drive.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Such directories are usually created by Windows Update – each package is extracted into a temporary directory, and deleted after installation. The Passport is chosen for this since it shows up as a local (not removable) disk and has the largest amount of free space.

They are usually safe to delete if older than a few days.

Comment: Arg! I totally forgot about that. Deleting my other comment.